# Surjective maps and induced cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology

Let $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ denote a continuous map between either manifolds or Lie groups. This map induces a homomorphism on cohomologies with coefficients in a ring $R$, denoted by $C(f) : H^*(Y, R) \longrightarrow H^*(X, R).$

How can we establish or intuitively grasp the correctness of the assertion that if the image of a non-trivial higher-order fundamental class in the cohomology of $Y$ is non-trivial, then $f$ must be surjective? Further, is the converse of this statement also true? Moreover, can this result be easily derived from the perspective of category theory?

I appreciate your patience with my series of questions.

Comment: What’s a fundamental class in the cohomology of an arbitrary topological space?

Comment: The generator of nth cohomology group of the topological space is the nth fundamental class of cohomology group or ring.

Comment: If $X = S^2$ and $Y = S^1 \vee S^2$, with $f: X \to Y$ the obvious inclusion map, then this induces an isomorphism in $H^2$ but the map $f$ is not surjective. You should be able to come with a similar example with topological groups and a map $G \to G \times H$.

Comment: What do you mean by "The generator of nth cohomology group" and in particular the word "the"? What if the cohomology group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ or some other non-cyclic abelian group?

Comment: Sorry! There should be "a" not "the".

Comment: Thank you for the counter-example. I am refining my question to focus on manifold or Lie groups.

Comment: Why would you expect surjectivity? I suggest you work out some 2-dimensional examples.

Comment: I found it in an article by Thom and Klyachko. Where he used this argument that top dimensional cohomology class does not vanish to show that certain word maps are not homotpic to nonsurjective map.